# What are the WebGL equivalents of the various globalCompositeOperation modes?

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl, globalcompositeoperation

When using a 2d canvas, I can set a variety of blend modes using globalCompositeOperation. WebGl/OpenGl enables similar compositing operations using blend mode, but it's operations are more inscrutable. I'd like some guidance on reproducing the various effects seen here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation

Does anybody know of a reference like that? Or I could even take a look at some rendering source code since I imagine the browsers may use OpenGl under the hood.

Comment: The OpenGL blend functions provide only a limited set of operations, most of the blending modes provided by `globalCompositeOperation` have to be implemented manually in OpenGL using a shader. [Blending Mode](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/144760-Blending-Mode?p=1038940&viewfull=1#post1038940)

Comment: Thanks, given the math involved, I can see that you're right about needing shaders.

Comment: There's [Skia](https://github.com/google/skia/) which is used by Chrome, Firefox, and Android. [The shader fragments appear to be here](https://github.com/google/skia/blob/81abc43e6f0b1a789e1bf116820c8ede68d778ab/src/gpu/glsl/GrGLSLBlend.cpp)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to this. Much appreciated.

Comment: I presume that this means that browsers are rendering each  stroke/fill in a canvas to a texture, one at a time, and then reading from that source when rendering the next blended layer? That seems really inefficient. With that in mind, I struggle to understand why these particular blend modes were supported given the implications for the rendering engine. Am I missing something about their implementation? How can they read the color from the previous program when shaders are executed in parallel?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "executed in parallel". If you draw image1 then image2, every pixel of drawing image1 might be computed in parallel but image2 will not start drawing until image1 is done drawing (or at least the driver is required to work as though that was true. In other words the drive can go ahead and parallelize even more if it knows the results would be the same as if all of image1 as finished before drawing image2)